# Best way to draw pixel with hardware acceleration

Tags: c#, draw, pixel, hardware-acceleration

So I want to draw pixels on the screen in C#, first I thought about using OpenTK but their documentation barely doesn't work, and is really confusing and annoying as they don't tell you what to import so you need to go through them all. Anyway, what would be the best way or library to use to draw pixels on the screen using the GPU?

Comment: also is the System.Drawing library hardware accelerated?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with SkiaSharp: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp

Here you can find some samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing

And here you can find how to use it in OpenGL/ANGLE context, in order to make it render over GPU: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48940790/2448748